# Difference between UC and non-UC Bluetooth headsets when using them with PC and phone at the same time

Tags: bluetooth, desktop-computer, wireless-headset

I'm looking for a headset I could use to easily switch between calls on the phone and Skype calls on my PC. Jabra Stealth or Plantronics Voyager Edge seem to be the good candidates. They come with additional (and more expensive) UC option and I wonder if UC is really necessary for my needs.